# Passing environment variables from command line

Tags: serverless-framework

Is it possible to pass environment variable with `sls deploy` , `sls` doesn't seem to have switch like `-e` and the only possible way looks like having a seperate yaml file to manage variables and pass it on using "environment:" element in the serverless.yml file as mentioned in this  [article](https://medium.com/@purplecones/serverless-environment-variables-4ec818f67388).

Answer (score 5):

You can use serverless parameters

Parameters can be passed directly via CLI --param flag, following the pattern --param="<key>=<value>":

```
serverless deploy --param="domain=myapp.com" --param="key=value"
```

Parameters can then be used via the ${param:XXX} variables:

```
provider:
  environment:
    APP_DOMAIN: ${param:domain}
    KEY: ${param:key}
```

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/parameters

Answer (score 4):

You can use any arbitrary name for your environment variable and pass it to serverless.yml with:

```
serverless deploy --myEnvVar <value>
```

You reference this inside serverless.yml with:

```
environment:
  myLocalVar: ${opt:myEnvVar}
```

Comment: Looks like this approach has been deprecated but alternatives are being explored: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/9371

Comment: Further extends from tsuchumann comment, this approach is not supported in serverless v3.
The workaround can be
`serverless deploy envName=envValue`
And reference it in serverless.yml by
`Name: xxxxxxxx-${env:envName}`. The workaround from Tomer also works.