# How to use different env files for "dev" and "prod" stages in "aws-nodejs-typescript" template

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have created a serverless function using "*aws-nodejs-typescript*" template from "serverless". I want to use different .env files for both "**dev**" and "**prod**" stages. How can we achieve that?

When i deploy it, i don't get the correct *stage*.

Can someone please advise ?

Here's my "**serverless.ts**" file.

```
import type { AWS } from '@serverless/typescript';

import {verify} from '@functions/order';


const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: 'sample-api-aws',
  frameworkVersion: '3',
  plugins: ['serverless-esbuild', 'serverless-offline'],
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    timeout: 300,
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
      shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    },
    environment: (() => {
      const stage = this.provider.getStage();
      console.log(`Environment is : `, stage);
      switch (stage) {
        case 'dev':
          return require('./dev.env').default;
        case 'prod':
          return require('./prod.env').default;
        default:
          return {};
      }
    })(),
  },
  // import the function via paths
  functions: { verify},
  package: { individually: true },
  custom: {
    esbuild: {
      bundle: true,
      minify: false,
      sourcemap: true,
      exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
      target: 'node14',
      define: { 'require.resolve': undefined },
      platform: 'node',
      concurrency: 10,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

Here's how i deploy this function in "dev" and in "prod"

### Dev

```
serverless offline start --httpPort 3171 --lambdaPort 3172 --stage dev --noTimeout
```

### Prod

```
serverless deploy -s prod --aws-profile my_profile
```

### Note:

I want to pass an environment file instead of passing arguments va command-line during deployment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing environment variables from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310730/passing-environment-variables-from-command-line)

Comment: @Xiduzo This works when you're using serverless.yml file. But the template i'm using have serverless.ts file. This method is not working here. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit, finally found the solution. This can be achieved using *serverless-dotenv-plugin*. https://github.com/neverendingqs/serverless-dotenv-plugin.

All i had to do was install this plugin and use it in my serverless.ts file like this

```
 plugins: ['serverless-esbuild', 'serverless-offline','serverless-dotenv-plugin']
```

It read the environment variables from my *.env.dev* or *.env.prod* based on the **--stage** value in serverless deploy command.

Hope someone else also finds this helpful!